# How to get the number of returns below a threshold in R?

Tags: r

I want to check how many times the daily returns fall below a particular % in R, could someone please help me figure this out? I am attempting to do this using `quantmod`.

I am new to R, and I hope I did the initial step of collecting the data correctly:

```
getSymbols("AAPL")
prices<-AAPL[, "AAPL.Close"]
returns<-diff(log(prices))
```

That is as far as I got. How can I know how many times did the return fall below a specific threshold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty simple to define a function to do that:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("AAPL")
prices = AAPL[, "AAPL.Close"]
returns = diff(log(prices))

countThresh = function(returns, threshold) sum(returns < threshold, na.rm = TRUE)
countThresh(returns, 0.01)  # 1556
```

In your example, the daily Apple returns are below 1% 1556 times.

Comment: Thanks fg nu, I really appreciate t and it was a great help

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `table` function

```
table(returns < threshold_value)
```

This would give the number of times the `return` exceeds and falls below the threshold value.

Updating the solution according to OP's comments

To get the dates, you can try

```
index(returns[returns < threshold_value])
```

Comment: wonderful, thank you very much. One more question, how do I list all the dates where the returns fall below that threshold? given that it is an xts-zoo class?

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Shah, I sincerely appreciate it. You have contributed greatly to my learning process